# Read specific attributes in XML - Laravel orchestra Parser

Tags: php, xml, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.5 & **Orchestra Parser** package for the read xml.
here is my XML

```
<OrderDetails>
       <SKU>3023071-103-7</SKU>
       <VariantArticle>3023071-103013</VariantArticle>
       <DateTime>
            <Date DateQualifier="ReqDelDate">2019-07-02</Date>
        </DateTime>
        <DateTime>
            <Date DateQualifier="CancelDate">2019-10-31</Date>
        </DateTime>
        <DateTime>
            <Date DateQualifier="Ex-FactoryDate">2019-07-26</Date>
        </DateTime>
 <OrderDetails>
```

I need to get values separately from `<DateTime>***</DateTime>` according to XML attributes

I'm currently doing like this

```
    $xml = XmlParser::load('/path to xml/book1.xml');
    return $order = $xml->parse([
        'poDateType'  => ['uses' => 'Orders.DateTime.Date::DateQualifier'],
        'poDate'  => ['uses' => 'OrderDetails.DateTime.Date'],            
    ]);
```

But I get only first `<DateTime>` result only.I need to get each attribute & it's value. how can I fix this.?

Comment: Looking at the feature tests, you don't define it to be a list. https://github.com/orchestral/parser/blob/master/tests/Feature/DocumentTest.php#L52